# Unable to create new session id when we run 2 or more than project

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, browser, session-cookies

When we run 2-3 projects on same browser, we are getting same session id. I need to know that how to create a new session id for other's project(including it's tab). So old projects(with it's tab) and new projects (with it's tab) have different session id without closing the tab or browser.

Comment: Is it same site/application in same domian?

Comment: I am using my created js file in both the project.

Comment: Application's are different but I have attached the same js file in both.

Comment: Can share uour code about session

Comment: Sorry, I can't but I am using sessionStorage and localStorage.

Comment: // Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();

Comment: Ok how do you get sessionid from server when you get sessionid then write on storage with your app prefix

Comment: // Get the text field that we're going to track
var field = document.getElementById("field");
 
// See if we have an autosave value
// (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
  // Restore the contents of the text field
  field.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
}
 
// Listen for changes in the text field
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // And save the results into the session storage object
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.value);
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use below code for your aim,
[image: view on console and storage]

```
    var params = null;
var appName = 'oldApp';
var savingData = {
    param1:'data1',
    param2:'data2',
    param3:'data3'
}
sessionStorage.setItem(appName, JSON.stringify(savingData))
var appName = 'newApp';
var savingData = {
    param1:'data1-for new',
    param2:'data2-for new',
    param3:'data3-for new'
}
sessionStorage.setItem(appName, JSON.stringify(savingData))
params = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('oldApp'));
console.log(params);
sessionStorage.getItem('newApp');
params = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('newApp'));
console.log(params);
```